# Unable to Get View Class in the top

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification

I am trying to get current view open in my code using this code in delegate while handling Push Notification

```
NSArray *views = window.subviews;
NSLog(@"views: %@", views);
UIView *topview=[views lastObject];
```

when is click on topview and see using below tool (eye mark) it shows the current view 
open [image].
But when i am try to get its kind of class using below two method none of these work

```
 for(UIView *view in window.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"view is a MyClass\n");
        }
    }
```

or

```
 if ([topview  isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]])  
    {
        NSLog(@"topview is a MyClass\n");
     }
    else
     {
        NSLog(@"topview is NOT a MyClass\n");
    }
```

How can i get my visible view name of kind of class.

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.viewControllers returns a UIViewController* array, not a UIView* array.

So, for your first solution:

```
for(UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if([viewController.view isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"view is a MyClass\n");
    }
}
```

will work.

For the visible UIViewController*, you can use:

```
UIViewController* viewController = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
```

For the topmost view:

```
UIView* topmostView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
```

Comment: Updated a bit. By the way, why are you trying a solution with navigation controller, if you're not using any?